# Native HTML5 Drag and Drop in touch devices

Tags: html, ipad, drag-and-drop, touch, draggable

I developed a HTML5 drag and drop based on tutorial from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

It work ok on desktops browsers, but does not work on touch devices (I am testing on iPad).

Someone know how can I handle the drag events on touch devices?

Answer (score 1):

Some HTML5 native events work in WebKit eg touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel but not all of them.

Generally, drag/drop and touch do not really play nicely together.

Better to look at the various touch frameworks and use the built-in gestures.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/OEBPS" xmlns:ibooks="http://apple.com/ibooks/html-extensions">
<head>
    <title>Demo 2: Drag and drop</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* CSS for the demo. CSS needed for the scripts are loaded dynamically by the scripts */
    #mainContainer{
        width:600px;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        padding:2px;
    }

    #capitals{
        width:200px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#E2EBED;
        padding:3px;
        height:400px;
    }
    #countries{
        width:300px;
        float:right;
            margin: 4px 61px 3px -8px;
        height:400px;
    }   
    #labels{
        width: 120px;
        float:right;
              margin: -403px 116px 3px -8px;
        height:400px;
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    }   
    .dragableBox,.dragableBoxRight{
        width:80px;
            height: 10px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#FFF;      
        margin-bottom:5px;
        padding:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .dragableBox,.labelBoxRight{
        width:80px;
            height: 10px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#FFF;      
        margin-bottom:5px;
        padding:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div.dragableBoxRight{
    height: 31px;
        width:110px;
        /*float:left;*/
        margin-right:5px;
        padding:5px;
        background-color:#D3D3D3;
        border: 1px dashed;
    }
    div.labelBoxRight{
               height: 31px;
        width:110px;
        /*float:left;*/
        margin-right:5px;
        padding:5px;
        background-color:#E2EBED;
    }
    .dropBox{
        width:190px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#E2EBED;
        height:400px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:3px;
        overflow:auto;
    }       
    a{
        color:#F00;
    }

    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
    img{
        border:0px;
    }   
    </style>    

</head>
<body>  

    <div id="mainContainer">

        <div id="capitals">

            <div id="dropContent">
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box1">Br<sup>&#x002B;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box2">Br<sup>&#x2212;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box3">CN<sup>&#x2212;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box4">NO<sub>2</sub><sup>&#x002B;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box5">NO<sub>2</sub><sup>&#x2212;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box6">NH<sub>2</sub><sup>&#x2212;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box7">RC=C<sup>&#x2212;</sup></div>
                <div class="dragableBox" id="box8">MeCO<sup>&#x002B;</sup></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="countries">
            <div id="box106" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box107" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box101" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box104" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box105" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box102" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box103" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>
            <div id="box108" class="dragableBoxRight"></div>


        </div>
        <div id="labels">
            <div id="boxl106" class="labelBoxRight">nucleophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl107" class="labelBoxRight">Electrophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl101" class="labelBoxRight">nucleophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl104" class="labelBoxRight">Electrophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl105" class="labelBoxRight">nucleophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl102" class="labelBoxRight">Electrophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl103" class="labelBoxRight">nucleophiles</div>
            <div id="boxl104" class="labelBoxRight">nucleophiles</div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="konaBody"></div>
    </div>

<div id="debug"></div>
<input type="button" value="reset" name="reset" onclick="r1();"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag-drop-custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />-->

<script type="text/javascript">
     <![CDATA[

// Custom drop action for the country boxes
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y)
{
    var targetObj = document.getElementById(targetId);  // Creating reference to target obj
    var subDivs = targetObj.getElementsByTagName('div');    // Number of subdivs
    if(subDivs.length>0 && targetId!='capitals')return; // Sub divs exists on target, i.e. element already dragged on it. => return from function without doing anything
    var sourceObj = document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem);   // Creating reference to source, i.e. dragged object
    var numericIdTarget = targetId.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'')/1;    // Find numeric id of target
    var numericIdSource = idOfDraggedItem.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'')/1; // Find numeric id of source

    if(numericIdTarget-numericIdSource==100){   // In the html above, there's a difference in 100 between the id of the country and it's capital(example:
                                                // Oslo have id "box1" and Norway have id "box101", i.e. 1 + 100.
        sourceObj.style.backgroundColor='#0F0'; // Set green background color for dragged object
    }else{
        sourceObj.style.backgroundColor=''; // Reset back to default white background color
    }
    if(targetId=='capitals'){
    // Target is the capital box - append the dragged item as child of first sub div, i.e. as child of <div id="dropContent">
        targetObj = targetObj.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];   

    }
    targetObj.appendChild(sourceObj);   // Append   
}

function r1()
{


}

var dragDropObj = new DHTMLgoodies_dragDrop();  // Creating drag and drop object

// Assigning drag events to the capitals
dragDropObj.addSource('box1',true); // Make <div id="box1"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box2',true); // Make <div id="box2"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box3',true); // Make <div id="box3"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box4',true); // Make <div id="box4"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box5',true); // Make <div id="box4"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box6',true); // Make <div id="box4"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box7',true); // Make <div id="box4"> dragable. slide item back into original position after drop
dragDropObj.addSource('box8',true); 

// Assigning drop events on the countries
dragDropObj.addTarget('box101','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box102','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box103','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box104','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box105','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box106','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('box107','dropItems');
dragDropObj.addTarget('box108','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop
dragDropObj.addTarget('capitals','dropItems'); // Set <div id="leftColumn"> as a drop target. Call function dropItems on drop

dragDropObj.init(); // Initizlizing drag and drop object
    ]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this simple code of javascript is not working even i used <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>   this is XHTML file i am try to run in ipad but not works please give the solution ..